# Matlab: Sum of 2nd column in matrix for equal values in 1st column

Tags: matrix, sum, multiple-columns

i would like to sum all the values from my 2nd column which have the same value in the first column.
So my matrix looks maybe like this:

> 1. column: [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 5]
> 2. column: [3 5 8 2 6 4 0 6 1 0 2 6]

now i would like to have for the value 1 in the 1st column a sum of 3, 5 and 8 in the 2nd column, the same goes for 2, 3 and so from the 1st column.
Like this for example:

> [1  2  3  4  5],
>   [16 8  11 0  8]

i'm thankful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum all values when values are equal :

```
Just to init :
a = [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 5 ; 3 5 8 2 6 4 0 6 1 0 2 6];
a = a.';
```

Let's go :

```
n=0
for i=1:size(a,1)
   if a(i,1) == a(i,2)
      n = n + a(i,1) 
   end 
end
n
```

**For the second question :**

```
mat=0
for j = 1:max(a(:,1))
    n=0
        for i=1:size(a,1)
           if j == a(i,1)
              n = n + a(i,2) 
           end
        end
    mat(j,1) = j
    mat(j,2) = n
end
mat
```

Result :

```
mat =

     1    16
     2     8
     3    11
     4     0
     5     8
```